# Getting started with Sharepoint 2007 development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

We have an ASP.NET website that we use internally to do some project tracking and various work. We would like to integrate some pieces of it to co-exist with Sharepoint2007 WSS.

Basically what we would really need to do is be able to add items to a list in one of the Sharepoint sites.

I'm not sure where to begin. I've looked online a bit but it seems overly complicated. Is there a quick start guide somewhere that can get me rolling with ease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint Web Services would be a logical place to start. In my opinion this would be the easiest way to build interaction between ASP.NET and SharePoint.

A [list of available web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx) can be found on MSDN.

If adding items to a list is the primary goal, then check out the [`UpdateListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of the [`Lists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service.

With the scope narrowed to Web Services, you can certainly find tutorials/references online. However, this [InfoQ post by Trent Swanson](http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services) is a decent introduction to SP web services. Note that they recommend generating .NET types using XSD files; in practice, for simple projects I have simply parsed the XML myself using LINQ. You can make it as easy or complex as you like, I suppose.

Comment: The XSD stuff is really what was confusing me. I wasn't sure if that was necessary or not.

Comment: Definitely not necessary. For a larger project, I might consider generating the actual types. But if you have a decent knowledge of XPath and/or LINQ, you can do what you need to do (especially if most of your work will be adding to the List and not querying it).

Comment: Thanks for the great and concise explanation!